# Modernizr doesn't work in IE - HTML5 input field validation not working

Tags: html, modernizr

Hi kind people of the internet,

Why doesn't Modernizr work in IE for a simple HTML5 input field?

I posted something similar yesterday, but didn't seem to explicitly explain the issue clearly enough, as the answers seem to point towards loading/referencing yet more libraries to shim/crutch IE.

Here's my page: http://www.msa.saccounty.net/utilitybilling/streetview/TestHTML5pagev6.aspx

I'm attempting to validate the input of an account number using HTML5 as follows:

```
<label for="account">Account Number: </label> 
<input id="account" name="inputAccount" 
 placeholder="input billing account number" 
 pattern="/(^500)|^\d{11}" 
 required
 autofocus
 type="text"/>
```

If I'm understanding things properly, by referencing Modernizr on my page, HTML5 should simply work in old browsers, including IE?...or am I being naive?...if Modernizr doesn't really fix anything for IE, then I'm a bit befuddled about what all the hype is.

Things work great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari...but alas not in IE8.  So what might I be doing wrong with Modernizr?...in theory I shouldn't have to use yet-another js library to make HTML5 work in IE.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Modernizr *does not* make HTML5 "work" in browsers, but allows you to *detect* HTML5 features so you can have a fallback solutions for old browsers while taking advantage of HTML5 features in the browsers that *do* understand them.

It is feature *detection* and nothing more, used for [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). Basically you use Modernizr to check if a feature exists. If so, use it. If not - use a fallback

Comment: Ohhhhh...my bad. And thanks for your patience.  Somehow I was too dense to absorb that fact in my excitement to think I was somehow going to magically get out of extra coding.  Not sure where I got this impression?...maybe from reading about the HTML5 Shim being built in?

Comment: I didn't mean to sound impatient, I had the same idea too at first and was disappointed when I found out what Modernizr actually does. Like a year ago there was a ton of hype around HTML5 and CSS3, and everyone was saying to use it (Modernizr). Personally, I have not found any use for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the [first paragraph of the Modernizr documentation](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/):

> Modernizr is a small JavaScript library that *detects* the availability of native implementations for next-generation web technologies, i.e. features that stem from the HTML5 and CSS3 specifications. Many of these features are already implemented in at least one major browser (most of them in two or more), and **what Modernizr does is, very simply, tell you whether the current browser has this feature natively implemented or not.**

(My emphasis at the end [theirs at the beginning].)

The hype is that all of this feature-checking is pre-built, comprehensive, maintained, and (in some cases) non-trivial.

Comment: I'll have to take another closer look at what all the HTML5 Shim was supposedly suppose to take care of...but mucho thanks for the feed back, as I really appreciate this: Stackoverflow is great!

Comment: @woody: If you mean [this HTML5 shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/), all it does is make IE recognise that the new elements are, in fact, elements (otherwise, IE won't style them correctly and such). It doesn't do anything to add placeholders or validation or similar. There are some projects that do this and that (including my own [place5](http://code.google.com/p/place5/) plugin for jQuery, which does the `placeholder` stuff), but I don't think there's anything that does **all** of it.